# Using JSON string as html attribute to form helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display a text box with some JSON in its data attribute. Here is what I do

```
<%= f.text_field :time, "data-options" => '{"mode": "timebox"}' %>
```

but it renders the following HTML

```
<input data-options="{&quot;mode&quot;: &quot;timebox&quot;}" ...
```

What I want to achieve is

```
<input data-options='{"mode": "timebox"}' ...
```

I want it to enclose the attribute in single quotes without escaping the contents. Can I do it with text_field helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that the JSON data will always be safe, use `html_safe` or `raw`:

```
#html_safe
<%= f.text_field :time, "data-options" => '{"mode": "timebox"}'.html_safe %>

#raw
<%= f.text_field :time, "data-options" => raw('{"mode": "timebox"}') %>
```

Ps. Note that I have used single quotes instead of double quotes for `mode` and `timebox`. (because for some reason, Rails always adds double-quotes around the attributes value when rendered in HTML).

Comment: Thank you, Zabba. I have tried this, but I need JSON values to be enclosed in double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: JSON needs double quotes `window.JSON.parse("{'mode': 'timebox'}")` does not work. I believe Rails needs to find a way to do this.